# Should Enum class filenames be suffixed with 'Enum'?

Tags: c#, enums, naming-conventions, filenames

When breaking out classes into files, I am wondering what the naming convention is for class files containing only enums. Should they match the enum name, like any other class, or should they be suffixed with 'Enum' so that the developer knows that the file contains only an enum?

**For example:**

```
namespace MyCompanyName.MyApplication
{
    public enum Colors
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Green,
        Yellow
    }
}
```

Would you say the file containing the above code should be named 'Colors.cs' or 'ColorsEnum.cs'? Alternatively, perhaps there is another accepted naming convention for such files?

Comment: No.  You picked the worst possible example, nobody will understand why Colors.Orange isn't valid.  Calling it ColorsEnum does not help.  But that all gets sorted out by IntelliSense.  You may assume it is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, this is a complete personal/team preference thing.

That being said:

I personally would name it `Colors.cs`.  This keeps the filename corresponding to the type name.  When I'm working on the API, if "Colors" are a fixed set of things represented by an enum, I'd probably know that, and there would be no confusion.

Comment: I prefer it to be singular rather than plural. See Microsoft guidlines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/4x252001(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 11):

The file name in my opinion should be the same as the name of the Enum, which - according to the [Enum Naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001%28VS.71%29.aspx) should **not** have an Enum suffix. Also the guideline suggests your enum should be *singular* so taking both into account it should be `Color.cs`

Answer (score 3):

What about creating a folder called Enums and naming the file Colors.cs?

Comment: I agree with this. If a file only contains a single object declaration I find it useful that the filename be the same as the object.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a folder called Enumerations, Enums or something descriptive should be enough.
Also you can follow the C# naming standards that said:

"Names of Enumerations
Do not use a prefix on enumeration value names. For example, do not use a prefix such as ad for ADO enumerations, or rtf for rich text enumerations, and so on.

This also implies that you should not include the enumeration type name in the enumeration value names. The following code example demonstrates incorrectly naming an enumeration's values.

C# code as follows

```
public  enum Teams
{
    TeamsAlpha,
    TeamsBeta,
    TeamsDelta
}
```

References:
[Names of Classes, Structs, and Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx)

Comment: I am aware that the type name should not contain a prefix or suffix, but this question is specifically asking in reference to the filename.

Comment: You can't just copy someone else's content and redistribute it like this, that's what “Copyright X, all rights reserved” means. By posting on Stack Exchange, you declare that you have the right to distribute the post content under a [CC BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. Please write an answer in your own words (and possibly link to an external site for more information).

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of how namespacing and folder structure can make your directory more readable. My company sticks enum types in an `_enumeration` file but leaves them in the same namespace as the classes that are primarily using those enums. It's a matter of preference, you should do whatever is most readble to you and your teammates. I would not use any sort of Hungarian-esque notation in your folder structure.